# How divide the values and place in next column according to conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas

[image]

```
print (df)
      Q Name Region username
15        RF  India  Karthik
12  INTERNET    NaN     Paul
9   INTERNET  India      Raj
10  INTERNET  India      Ram
11  INTERNET  China      Xin
13     TOOLS  china     Zang
14     TOOLS  china     chin
```

Above is the dataframe I want OUTPUT should be
 If all memmbers are india then put YEs in ALLINDIA 
 If  memmbers contains atleast one india then put YEs in AtleastoneINDIA
If  memmbers does not contain atleast one india then put YEs in non_INDia

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) for boolean mask and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and functions [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html)
[`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html), then create new column by invert `any` function per rows and last [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df1 = (df['Region'].eq('India')
                   .groupby(df['Q Name'])
                   .agg(['all','any'])
                   .assign(non= lambda x: ~x.any(axis=1))
                   .add_suffix('_india'))
print (df1)
          all_india  any_india  non_india
Q Name                                   
INTERNET      False       True      False
RF             True       True      False
TOOLS         False      False       True
```

Also is possible small modification for change `True`s of `any` if also in `all` column:

```
df1 = (df['Region'].eq('India')
                   .groupby(df['Q Name'])
                   .agg(['all','any'])
                   .assign(non= lambda x: ~x.any(axis=1),
                           any = lambda x: x['any'] & ~x['all'])
                   .add_suffix('_india'))
print (df1)
          all_india  any_india  non_india
Q Name                                   
INTERNET      False       True      False
RF             True      False      False
TOOLS         False      False       True
```

Last for `yes` values use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1, 'yes', ''), 
                   index=df1.index, 
                   columns=df1.columns)
print (df2)
         all_india any_india non_india
Q Name                                
INTERNET                 yes          
RF             yes                    
TOOLS                              yes
```